# How I unlink deleted global package?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-link

I had linked one package with the command `npm link` inside the package folder and then I delete it and I can't unlink the package from npm global list.

Comment: A dumb sugestion but it might work. Install it again, unlink and then delete it

Comment: It was linked package.. if you deleted it there is no easy way to build the whole library again.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `npm -g list --depth=0` you will see the broken path right?

Suppose the deleted package folder named `demolib`.

Create new folder with the same name like previous `demolib`

Run inside the folder `npm init -y` to create package.json  file.

Then, inside the folder run `npm unlink` and npm will removes the broken symbolic link from global npm list